# Referencing 3D objects in React JS using Three JS Library

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I would to reference some 3D models loaded with GLTFLoader inside my app. I'm using React js and the Threejs Library. I have a Render Component which basically create the scene and threejs renderer inside one useEffect, and then I just call < Render /  >  inside the main app.js. I don't know how should I reference a model loaded in this way :

```
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load('scene.gltf', function (gltf) {


      gltf.scene.scale.set(.1, .1, .1);
      gltf.scene.position.set(.1, 4.1, .1);
      //How do I get a reference to gltf.scene to manipulate 
   //later outside of the scope of this function ?
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
}, undefined, function (error) {

  console.error(error);

});
```

I would like something like a useState to hold a reference to a gltf.scene, so I can manipulate it later as with game scripts.

Comment: so why not using `useState` ? you can also use `useRef` to create an instance variable

Comment: I've tried useState. Like. const [player,setPlayer] = React.useState(null). Inside the function i use setPlayer(gltf.scene), out side the function when I try to acess player's atributes, player is null.